# link_thumbnailer undefined method `src' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using [link_thumbnailer](https://github.com/gottfrois/link_thumbnailer) gem to generate thumbnail image previews for websites that users submit in my rails app.

In the show page for each user's post , the image of their website loads up without issues, but loading the index page which displays all the recent submitted posts from all users, i keep getting both of these errors.

```
undefined method `src' for nil:NilClass
```

or

```
LinkThumbnailer::RedirectLimit
```

index.html.erb

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>   
<%= link_to (image_tag LinkThumbnailer.generate(post.url).images.first.src.to_s), post_path(post) , class: "ui small image" %>
    <p><%= link_to post.title, post_path(post) %></p>
    <p><%# post.tagline %></p> 
<% end %>
```

show.html.erb

```
<%= @post.title %> 
<%= link_to (image_tag LinkThumbnailer.generate(@post.url).images.first.src.to_s),"#{@post.url}", class: "ui centered large image"  %>

<%= @post.description %>


posted by <%= @post.user.username %>
<%= link_to "Visit Site", "#{@post.url}" , class: "ui secondary button" %>
```

Comment: According to the documentation, the redirect_limit is set to 3. Have you tried to change this limit?

Comment: yeah i had tried that and still having the same issues